# Will a nested function always have to be redefined?

Tags: javascript

For architecture and namespacing purposes, I want to do this:

```
function outer (arr) {
  function inner(arrElement) {
    return doStuffTo(arrElement); 
  }
  var results = [];

  arr.forEach(element, index, array) {
    results.push(inner(element));
  }
  return results;
}
```

So basically, a function within a function. Simple stuff. But `outer()` is something that will be executed *a lot*. Does this mean the overhead of defining a function (on top of evaluating it) will apply every time `outer()` is called? For this to be efficient, must I define `inner()` outside?

Comment: Yes, you should define it outside.

Comment: Are there any benchmarks on this?

Comment: If by *a lot*, you really mean *a lot*, then yes, definitely define it outside. Also consider using a native javascript iterator instead of `forEach` (yes, native javascript sucks at iteration, but function calls are expensive).

Comment: Also, I second @JamesMcLaughlin's request for benchmarks. It's possible the javascript engine already makes this optimization for you.

Comment: @BenLee, `forEach` is native in later versions of JS...

Comment: [mdn docs on `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach): looks to me like @Cerales has some incorrect `forEach` code.

Comment: You could define it ouside but as a property of `outer` so that it is still obviously related: `outer.inner = function() { ... }`

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin, defining the function outside is about 60% faster in Chrome: http://jsperf.com/function-inside-function (if you want, please verify that my test cases are sane)

Comment: I'm not actually going to be using forEach, it was just for cleanliness of my example. My C history makes me use standard `for(){}` for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a closure:

```
var outer = (function() {

  function inner(arrElement) {
    return doStuffTo(arrElement);
  }

  return function (arr) {
    var results = [];
    arr.forEach(element, index, array) {
      results.push(inner(element));
    }
    return results;
  }
}());
```

*inner* is held in a closure and remains "private" to *outer*, and is only created once when *outer* is initialised.

Comment: This is exactly what I want in terms of its impact on the namespace and structure, thanks!